# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d3.group is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data set of pokemon and I want to group them by type. So there will be group of pokemon that is type fire, water, grass etc... And **d3.js** has a function called [d3.group](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#group).

In the docs it states *`Groups` the specified iterable of values into a `Map` from key to array of value*. I tried following this [observable tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-group) and I keep getting the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d3.group is not a function`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code.
bar_chart.js

```js
drawBarChart = async() => {
  // 1. Access the data
  const dataset = await d3.csv('./pokemon.csv');
  console.log(dataset);

  pokemon = d3.group(dataset, d => d.type1)


  const metricAccesor = d => d.type1;

  // 2. create the dimensions
  const width = 600;
}

drawBarChart()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./bar_chart.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

[Pokemon dataset from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/pokemon?select=pokemon.csv)

Here is my code on [github](https://github.com/zaynaib/dataVizPractice/tree/master/Day5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API is not exactly clear: some new features in the `d3-array` mini library, like the mentioned `d3.group`, are not available in the bundle:

```js
console.log(d3.group)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

So, in that case you'll have to reference the [standalone](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) library:

```js
console.log(d3.group)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```

Therefore, this is what you need at the end of your `<body>`:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./bar_chart.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, try using the D3 Nest command, which for me did not require loading any other libraries.

https://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/

```
    .then(function (dataset) {
        return d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return d.type1; })
            .entries(dataset);
```